# Make GET request to SSO protected resource

Tags: python, ajax, https, xmlhttprequest, single-sign-on

I need to access data by making a GET call but the resource is protected by Single Sign On. I have the URI end-point, and Single Sign on credentials. I started off with making ajax request using XMLHttpRequest() but got this:

> blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

As I don't have access to the server, and thus can't set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to true, I decided to move to making calls using Python requests library with Flask backend. I tried to pass user credentials along with the GET request like this:

```
headers = {'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'}
r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(userid, password), headers=headers)
print r.status_code #prints 403
print r.content #prints 403 forbidden
```

Is there any way to access such a resource ?
Please note that SSO is configured using SAML 2.0

**UPDATE:**
After following up with the link suggested by giaco, I am now able to programmatically login to SSO. Atleast, I think so.. (the HTML returned by s.post(..) actually still has 403 forbidden code-- but when I hit the url in browser, it redirects to logged in page) However, when I send the GET request, I am again getting 403 FORBIDDEN message. Below is the updated code:

```
payload = {
    'UserName': username,
    'Password': password
    }
    print "configured payload" #successfully printed on console

    with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post("my_sso_url", data=payload)
        # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
        print p.text #Successfully printing the html code of an interstetial page which later redirects to logged-in page

        # An authorised request.

        r = s.get('secure web page url') #<------Line A
        print "sent get request" # gets printed on console
        print r.text # prints 403 FORBIDDEN
```

**UPDATE 2:**
So, I manually logged-in to SSO and then made the GET request on "Line A" in the code and still got 403 Forbidden. I may be wrong, but I believe it has something to do with the cookies i.e. maybe I need to pass some more info while making the GET request on Line A.
Any pointers/tips/help is much appreciated !

**UPDATE 3:**
Found kind-of similar implementation in C# using CA SSO. My server implements OASIS SAML though. Here is the link:
[HTTP request from a C# desktop application to a Siteminder-protected server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912430/http-request-from-a-c-sharp-desktop-application-to-a-siteminder-protected-server)
If anyone can please help me in translating C# code to python or provide any tips/pointers - it'll be a huge help ! Currently, I am having trouble with setting autoredirect to false in Python - applied the solution from [How do I prevent Python's urllib(2) from following a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554446/how-do-i-prevent-pythons-urllib2-from-following-a-redirect) but still getting 403 FORBIDDEN message.

Comment: Did you try with session https://stackoverflow.com/a/17633072/6555866?

Comment: Tried that but unable to decide what should be the "LOGIN_URL" in p = s.post('LOGIN_URL', data=payload) as this url is actually a redirect and contains various things like client_id, resource_id and nonce, and nonce keeps on changing everytime.

Comment: Getting error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 13774: character maps to <undefined> in print p.text

Comment: Okay ! So, after some trials, I figured out the correct "LOGIN_URL" , and I am now able to login to sso !! but when I send the GET request, I am getting 403 FORBIDDEN. Writing the update in question.

Comment: Looks like the `HTTPBasicAuth` is not passing correct parms; are you sure the `userid` & `password` are valid?

Comment: @pstatix - Actually, I found out that SAML 2.0 doesn't use HTTPBasicAuth. userid and password are correct - I use them to login everytime.